# I want to update the state object in immutable manner so that react and redux will work properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I want to update the firstName of the each user in the given javascript object in my redux reducer state in an immutable manner

I have tried many ways but none is working.

here is my data :

```
{"users":[{"key":1,"value":{"employeeID":1,"firstName":"Siddharth Kilam","mobileNumber":"+919987792049","adminName":"Sid Kilam","adminID":36,"profileName":"default","profileID":4,"explicitLogin":1,"locRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-09 09:15:05","lat":28.4453983,"lon":77.1012133,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":1},"attendanceRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-09 09:05:39","lat":28.4453983,"lon":77.1012133,"eventTypeID":8,"employeeID":1},"workingStatus":{"code":0,"reason":"Normal Day","shifts":[{"startTime":"2019-04-11T04:34:00.000Z","endTime":"2019-04-11T12:34:00.000Z"}]},"offlinePeriod":3600000,"status":"Inactive"}},{"key":145,"value":{"employeeID":145,"firstName":"SidKilam2 Motorola","mobileNumber":"9599936991","adminName":"Sid Kilam","adminID":36,"profileName":"default","profileID":4,"explicitLogin":1,"locRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-03 12:20:16","lat":28.4455203,"lon":77.101336,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":145},"attendanceRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-02 23:01:27","lat":28.4747009,"lon":77.0989274,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":145},"workingStatus":{"code":0,"reason":"Normal Day","shifts":[{"startTime":"1999-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","endTime":"2000-01-01T18:29:59.000Z"}]},"offlinePeriod":3600000,"status":"Offline"}}]};

My Current Reducer Function : 
 const newState = {
        ...state, // or state
        users: state.users.filter(user => {
          return user.value.status === online;
        })
      }

      return newState;
```

Comment: can you share the code via fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to spread the users object as well to preserve immutability as follows:

```
const newState = {
        ...state, 
        users: ([...state.users].filter(user => {
          return user.value.status === online;
        })).map(user => ({...user, value: {...user.value, firstName:"Vishal"}}));
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i'm getting an empty object returned when using this. I think need to handle the key and value prop inside it also

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` to do that.

```
const newState = {
    ...state, // or state
    users: state.users.filter(user => {
      return user.value.status === online;
    }).map(user => {return {...user, value: {...user.value, firstName:"new name"}};});
  }

  return newState;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i'm getting an empty object returned when using this. I think need to handle the key and value prop inside it also

Comment: You should double check the current `state` and your condition. First, current state doesnt have any user with status `online`. Second, the condition has mistake and it should be `user.value.status === 'online'`.

Comment: Yes that part is working i have online value is my original dataset but what i am asking about i think it's not complete but my ui is not re rendering after this.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I think the `map` should be `.map(user => {return {...user, value: {...user.value,firstName:"new name"}};});`